# Resize div when word wraps

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a table with fixed-width columns. If a column is sorted, I want to display an arrow icon to the left of its title. However, when the text in the title wraps, the div is not resized properly and the arrow gets pressed to the far left.

The following demo shows two columns. The left one has a short title and is correct. The right one has a long title and is not as desired: https://jsfiddle.net/79pfyxo6/

This is the CSS i use for the table titles:

```
.sortedColumn {
    float: right;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; 
}

.titleElement {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How can I change it so that the arrow of the second column is tight to the wrapped text like in this image: http://pasteboard.co/2xqPi8Nx.png

Comment: So do you mind if the column with the long title resizes to a wider column? Or do you want to keep it 150px but with the image next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check out with this css that may help you

```css
 td, th {
        background: #88FF88;    
        text-align: right;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    td {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .sortedColumn {
        float:right;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed; 
    }
    .arrow {
        width: 15px;
    }
    .sortedColumn {    
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed; 
    }    
    .sortedColumn img{
        vertical-align: middle; //added new 
    }
    .titleElement {
        display: initial;    // changed
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: @Martin Lanter please check out answer